# Creating a full-screen window in Windows API

Tags: c++, directx9, winapi

I've got a Windows API Window. I've managed to make it windowed, and "fullscreen windowed". But I can't seem to make the window just full-screen- for example, even if I specify `WS_POPUP`, I can still freely move the cursor to my second screen. However, if I launch full-screen games, they don't permit it, and exist only exclusively or minimized. How can I make a window that behaves this way?

Edit: Excuse me. Limiting the mouse movement was just one example of how a full-screen window behaves differently to a non-fullscreen window, I'm not looking for how to limit the mouse movement.

Or is this *set* in the D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS, rather than just communicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS has a BOOL called "Windowed" in it; you want to set that to false at the time you make your call to CreateDevice on your IDirect3D9 pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Limiting the mouse movement has previously been discussed here: [Mouse aim in an FPS](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7812/mouse-aim-in-an-fps)

Comment: Limiting the mouse movement is only one aspect of an exclusive full-screen game.

Comment: @DeadMG The question mainly seems to ask about the mouse aspect. It sounds like your creating your window ok (to cover the screen), then you also need to set "windowed" to false in the present parameters along with the width and height to the size of the screen. I don't have the SDK docs to hand but I'm pretty sure they talk you through all this stuff.