# How do I handle DirectX mouse events?

Tags: c++, directx, mouse

I am a beginner making my second game (simple low graphics FPS), in *Visual C++ 2010*. So far, I only know how to use keyboard controls. I've had source files like `keyboard.h` and `keyboard.ccp`, responding to callback functions like `kbd.UpIspressed()`.

How can I do this with mouse controls?

Comment: So far, we have nothing to work with. We don't know what you're using. Please include what information you can if you want an answer.

Comment: You could catch windows messages or use something like Directinput for simple mouse operations.

Comment: i got this series of tutorials from youtube its 'DirectX game programming...' by ChilliTomato some guy, He had me download a ready-made set of files some Framework ( some Black screen: where all the pixels plotted are displayed).

Comment: You could try using the thing in the framework that does something else, and maybe the other too.

Comment: sorry im could not understand you... i don't what was that framework... please check this... it was my reference.. www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kpSiitk4eI

Comment: My previous comment was designed to leave out all detail that could be used to make it understandable. This site exists for you upon becoming stuck to ask us a question, after having researched what you can, to help you find a solution. If you don't know the problem, we most certainly do not. Context is everything, friend, and my previous comment only contains slightly less than your question.

Comment: I edited to clarify, but the title and body still ask different questions. Do you want to know *how to make a mouse aim* or *how to respond to mouse events*?

Comment: @Anko Both if possible... :) mouse events > right click, left click and wheel + the mouse aim.

Comment: OK, I've edited it to be about *mouse events*, as we already have [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7812/mouse-aim-in-an-fps?rq=1) on mouse aim generally.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using win32 then you can handle mouse and keyboard events using RawInput. Info can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You would handle windows messages for raw input devices in the window process.
For example, if handling the input for a keyboard and mouse, register those devices in the WM_CREATE case of your application window process like so:

```
switch( uMsg ){ 
case WM_CREATE:
{
    // register raw input devices
    RAWINPUTDEVICE rID[2];

    // Keyboard
    rID[0].usUsagePage = 1;
    rID[0].usUsage = 6;
    rID[0].dwFlags = 0;
    rID[0].hwndTarget=NULL;

    // Mouse
    rID[1].usUsagePage = 1;
    rID[1].usUsage = 2;
    rID[1].dwFlags = 0;
    rID[1].hwndTarget = hWnd;
    if ( !RegisterRawInputDevices( rID, 2, sizeof( RAWINPUTDEVICE ) ) )
    {
        // handle failure
    }
    ...
    break;
}
```

Then in the same process handle the raw input messages with WM_INPUT like so:

```
switch( uMsg )
{
    ...
    case WM_INPUT:
    {       
        RAWINPUT *pRI = NULL;

        // Determine how big the buffer should be
        UINT iBuffer;
        GetRawInputData( ( HRAWINPUT )lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &iBuffer, sizeof( RAWINPUTHEADER ) );

        // Allocate a buffer with enough size to hold the raw input data
        LPBYTE lpb = new BYTE[ iBuffer ];
        if( lpb == NULL )
            return 0;

        // Get the raw input data
        UINT readSize = GetRawInputData( ( HRAWINPUT )lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &iBuffer, sizeof( RAWINPUTHEADER ) ) ;

        // Validate that read size is as expected
        if( readSize != iBuffer )
            puts( "ERROR: GetRawInputData didn't return correct size!" ) ;
        pRI = ( RAWINPUT* )lpb;             

        // Process the Mouse Messages
        if( pRI->header.dwType== RIM_TYPEMOUSE )
        {
            raw.riProcessMouseMessage( &pRI->data.mouse );
        }

        // Process the Keyboard Messages
        if( pRI->header.dwType== RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD )
        {
            raw.riProcessKeyboardMessage( &pRI->data.keyboard );
        }

        // Destroy the Raw Input Data and Return
        SAFE_DELETE( lpb );
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The 'raw.riProcessMouseMessage() and raw.riProcessKeyboardMessage() functions come from a class I use to keep track of raw input keyboard and mouse states...I found this on a raw input tutorial( that I can't find right now ). Here are the function definitions:

```
USHORT keyState[256];
short mouseState[5];
short mzr;
long mxr, myr;

USHORT MASKDOWN[ 5 ] = { RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN, 
RI_MOUSE_RIGHT_BUTTON_DOWN, 
RI_MOUSE_MIDDLE_BUTTON_DOWN, 
RI_MOUSE_BUTTON_4_DOWN, 
RI_MOUSE_BUTTON_5_DOWN };

USHORT MASKUP[ 5 ] = { RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_UP, 
RI_MOUSE_RIGHT_BUTTON_UP, 
RI_MOUSE_MIDDLE_BUTTON_UP, 
RI_MOUSE_BUTTON_4_UP, 
RI_MOUSE_BUTTON_5_UP };

void riManager::riProcessMouseMessage( const RAWMOUSE *rmouse )
{
    // Store Mouse Button States
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {       
        if( MASKDOWN[ i ] & rmouse->usButtonFlags )
            mouseState[ i ] = 1;
        else if( MASKUP[ i ] & rmouse->usButtonFlags )
            mouseState[ i ] = 0;            
    }
    // Check Mouse Position Relative Motion
    if ( MOUSE_MOVE_RELATIVE == rmouse->usFlags )   
    {
        mxr = rmouse->lLastX ;      
        myr = rmouse->lLastY ;  
    }

    // Check Mouse Wheel Relative Motion
    mzr = ( RI_MOUSE_WHEEL & rmouse->usButtonFlags ) ? ( short )( rmouse->usButtonData ) : 0;
}
void riManager::riProcessKeyboardMessage( const RAWKEYBOARD *rkey )
{   
    // Store New Key State
    keyState[ rkey->VKey ] &= 0xfe; 
    keyState[ rkey->VKey ] |= 1 - ( RI_KEY_BREAK & rkey->Flags );
}
```

It will be up to you to manage these variables. Build a class to hold the variables, then you can access the key and mouse states at will.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you should already have a [message pump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Simply add `WM_MOUSEMOVE` as one of the message types you handle and check the message parameters to determine mouse position.  Alternatively, you can use [raw input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want to support ultra low-latency or sub-pixel motion.